# Spring Boot OAuth 2 Get Logger Username

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, httpsession

I have no clue how to obtain current logged username from spring boot oauth 2. In addition, we have one auth server and multiple systems and we want to make sso between them. Futhermore, we also need to work with session in each system. So the question is how we can get current username and session from each system.

Comment: You could use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` or can take `Principal principal` in controller method arguments.

Comment: Thanks, i need to check. How about obtaining session. Where we can save user related variables (not in database), we only need session;

Comment: Then you must use `Spring Session` which distributes session in distributed applications. Through this you can obtain session.

Comment: Thanks, i assume sso is stateless though. I need to check that. Well, some code samples please with sso+session?

Comment: This https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use JWT token where you can place necessary info and extract the info from the token.

http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/

Session is something which actually "conflicts" with SSO but you can try key/values storage to keep session info (e.g. Redis https://dzone.com/articles/using-redis-session-storage)

Comment: Well, thank you. But i do think that in sso it is possible. We do not want user to login again in each system. We want to sign in users only once